# React navigation - cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation

I have a create profile page and an auth page (where one enters a code sent by text). I'd like to navigate to the auth page, when a profile is created.

I have a component for the create profile page and one for the auth page.

Based on the example [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md).

Relevant code:

```
// CreateProfileComponent.js

import React from 'react';
..
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class CreateProfile extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    handleCreateProfile(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (condition) {
            createProfile(...);
            this.props.history.push('/auth');
        } else {
            // re-render
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // data-testid="create-profile" - workaround (https://kula.blog/posts/test_on_submit_in_react_testing_library/) for
            // https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1937
            <form onSubmit={this.handleCreateProfile.bind(this)} data-testid="create-profile">
                ...
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(CreateProfile);

// index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import CreateProfile from './CreateProfileComponent';
import { TokenEntry } from './TokenEntryComponent';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <ProtectedRoute exact path="/" component={ActivityList} />
    <Route path="/login" component={CreateProfile.WrappedComponent} />
    <Route path="/auth" component={TokenEntry} />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

//createprofilecomponent.test.js
import React from 'react';
import { 
    LocationProvider, 
    createMemorySource,
    createHistory
} from '@reach/router';
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import CreateProfile from '../CreateProfileComponent';

const source = createMemorySource('/login');
const history = createHistory(source);

let displayName = null;
let phoneNumber = null;
let legalAgreement = null;

global.window = { location: { pathname: null } };

function Wrapper({children}) {
    return <LocationProvider history={history}>{children}</LocationProvider>;
}
beforeEach(() => {
    render(
        <CreateProfile.WrappedComponent location={'/'} />, 
        { wrapper: Wrapper }
    );
});

it("navigates to /auth when good data entered", () => {
    // setup

    fireEvent.submit(screen.getByTestId('create-profile'));

    expect(global.window.location.pathname).toEqual('/auth');
});
```

I'm getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

during tests and in Chrome.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed

```
export default withRouter(CreateProfile);
```

To

```
export const CreateProfileWithRouter = withRouter(CreateProfile);
```

Changed

```
<Route path="/login" component={CreateProfileWithRouter.WrappedComponent} />
```

To

```
<Route path="/login" component={CreateProfileWithRouter} />
```

[Pull request created](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/7456) to include an example in withRouter's documentation.

Example [gist](https://gist.github.com/tavor/dbecb0f8303b16b129dbd7fcc6004300)

Answer (score 0):

Use the react-router-dom

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
```

Comment: Same result - react-router-dom 5.2.0